# How to use JaudioTagger to write data?

Tags: android, audio, jaudiotagger, mp3agic

I am trying to use `JaudioTagger 2.2.3` to edit tags of audio file but till now i have not achieved any success.
this is a test code to change the Artist tag of a `mp3` file in Internal Storage

```
String path;
try
{
  TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
  AudioFile f=AudioFileIO.read(new File(path));
  Tag t=f.getTag();
  t.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,Str);
  AudioFileIO.write(f);
}catch(CannotReadException e){}
 catch(TagException e){}
 catch(ReadOnlyException e){}
 catch(InvalidAudioFrameException e){}
 catch(CannotWriteException e){}
```

My Application is well elevated with `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
I am testing in Android version `Android 6.0`
this code throws `InvalidAudioFrameException` with a message

> `No audio header found within example.mp3`

Its not that the audio is corrupt as it shows similar error with other mp3s also
Also if any one has any other wat for audio tagging please do tell me and i have also used `mp3agic` which repeadedly shows:`example.mp3:open failed :EROFS(Read only file system)` on the line

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File(filePathStr+"example.mp3");
ID3v1 id3v1Tag;
if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
  id3v1Tag =  mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
} else {
  // mp3 does not have an ID3v1 tag, let's create one..
  id3v1Tag = new ID3v1Tag();
  mp3file.setId3v1Tag(id3v1Tag);
    }
  id3v1Tag.setTrack("5");
  id3v1Tag.setArtist("An Artist");
  id3v1Tag.setTitle("The Title");
  id3v1Tag.setAlbum("The Album");
  id3v1Tag.setYear("2001");
  id3v1Tag.setGenre(12);
  id3v1Tag.setComment("Some comment");
  mp3file.save("example.mp3")//error showing in this line
```

My question

- How to rectify Jaudiotagger?
- Is there any way to use Mp3agic as an alternative to Jaudiotagger?
- Or there is any other efficient way leaving these two?

I have also used [JaudioTagger-android](https://github.com/hexise/jaudiotagger-android) but same problem persists.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For the error when doing

```
mp3file.save("example.mp3")
```

i would recommend to not overwrite directly the old file. Try to create a new file, and then delete and rename to restore the original file setup.

```
song.save(location + "intermed");
File from = new File(location + "intermed");
File file = new File(location);
file.delete();
File to = new File(location);
from.renameTo(to);
```

Of course you need to add exception handling and what not, and also this will fail if you have no write permissions. This may be the case if you use a more recent Android version, i think above 4.4, and you try to access the SD card. Then, the write permissions need to be granted at runtime for specific folders, the manifest write permission is not sufficient. See Android's *Storage Access Framework*.